# Images source not updating in gatsby build using localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, gatsby

I'm trying to show different set of images for the users who visit the website for the first time using `localstorage`, everything works as expected in gatsby develop but when I build the site using gatsby build for production use it always returns images which meant to show only for the first time users. here is the full code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

let visited = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.localStorage.getItem('visited')
var items = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/40/200/300", 
  "https://picsum.photos/id/30/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/20/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/300"
]

class IndexPage extends Component {

  reTargetImages() {
        typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.localStorage.setItem("visited", JSON.stringify('1'));
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.reTargetImages()
  }

  render() {
    if(!visited) {
      items = [
        "https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/300", 
        "https://picsum.photos/id/30/200/300",
        "https://picsum.photos/id/20/200/300",
        "https://picsum.photos/id/40/200/300"
      ]
    }
    return (
      <main>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <h1>
          Congratulations
          <br />
          <span>— you just made a Gatsby site! </span>
          {items && items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <img id={`img-${index}`} src={`${item}`} />
            )
          })}
          </span>
        </h1>
      </main>
  )
  }
}

export default IndexPage
```

The code always returns images meant for first-time users even though the `localstorage` is set properly.
i'e

```
      [
        "https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/300", 
        "https://picsum.photos/id/30/200/300",
        "https://picsum.photos/id/20/200/300",
        "https://picsum.photos/id/40/200/300"
      ]
```

the issue occurs only in production build and works fine in development

Answer (score 0):

give the localstorage getitem statement before the condition check

```
...
visited = (typeof window !== 'undefined') && (window.localStorage.getItem('visited'));
console.log(visited);
if(!visited) {  
...
```

NB: give semicolumn to at end of each statement.

Comment: put a `console.log(visited)` before the condition check in the above solution and see what value you get in the production.

Comment: when i put console.log(visited) before if statement i get the correct value i'e "1"

Comment: add a key to img element. `<img  key={index} id={`img-`+index} src={item} />`

Comment: try with a different src also, for visited and non-visited

Comment: tried still no luck, here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-elgamal-vxbiv

Answer (score 0):

You should need to use the state to force a change of your `items` variable. A static approach is not suitable here (or may lead you to some unwanted behaviors). In addition, use boolean values to make your falsy conditions. Something like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

let visited = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.localStorage.getItem('visited')

class IndexPage extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {items: [      
      "https://picsum.photos/id/40/200/300", 
      "https://picsum.photos/id/30/200/300",
      "https://picsum.photos/id/20/200/300",
      "https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/300"
    ]};
   }
  
  reTargetImages() {
        typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.localStorage.setItem("visited", true));
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.reTargetImages()
  }

  render() {
    if(!visited) {
      this.setState({
         items: [
            "https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/300", 
           "https://picsum.photos/id/30/200/300",
           "https://picsum.photos/id/20/200/300",
           "https://picsum.photos/id/40/200/300"
         ]
      })
    }
    return (
      <main>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <h1>
          Congratulations
          <br />
          <span>— you just made a Gatsby site! </span>
          {this.state.items && this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <img key={`img-${index}`} id={`img-${index}`} src={item} />
            )
          })}
          </span>
        </h1>
      </main>
  )
  }
}

export default IndexPage
```

In addition, add the `key` attribute when using loops that render an element.

Keep in mind that you are setting as `true` (or `1` in your case) the `visited` variable in the `componentDidMount` so as soon as the DOM tree is loaded, it will match the `!visited` condition displaying your original `items`. I don't think if it's what you want to achieve, but this is the right way of changing the same variable to display different results with the same code, using the state.

I would also recommend you to add the `visited` variable in the state among your `localStorage` and changing both accordingly when needed.